# My breakpoints located after an http request does not work, how can I fix it?

Tags: http, debugging, stripe-payments, phpstorm, xdebug

I work on the PhpStorm IDE and I use Xdebug.

The `process_upgrade_membership()` function displays a form to register to my website (currently on my localhost). When I place a breakpoint on this function, it triggers.

The `recurring_payment_confirm()` function is triggered by an http request from Stripe when a payment has been made (`[200] POST http://localhost/mySite/index.php?option=com_osmembership&task=recurring_payment_confirm&payment_method=os_stripe [evt_1KYoa4HVMmgjDnLE4gsKXE5c]`). When I place a breakpoint on this function, the breakpoint is ignored. I also tried to put breakpoints in the functions used by `recurring_payment_confirm()` without success. I made sure that the function is used by testing it with a `dd()`.

These two functions are in the same file.

Can you help me debug what's after the http request?

xdebug_info() :

```
`Version    3.1.3
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business
Enabled Features
(through 'xdebug.mode' setting)
Feature Enabled/Disabled    Docs
Development Helpers ✘ disabled  
Coverage    ✘ disabled  
GC Stats    ✘ disabled  
Profiler    ✘ disabled  
Step Debugger   ✔ enabled   
Tracing ✘ disabled  
Optional Features
Compressed File Support no
Clock Source    GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime
Diagnostic Log
No messages
Step Debugging  Docs
Debugger    Active  
Connected Client    localhost:9003   
DBGp Settings
Max Children    100  
Max Data    1024     
Max Depth   1    
Show Hidden Properties  Yes  
Extended Properties Yes  
Notifications   Yes  
Resolved Breakpoints    Yes  
Breakpoint Details  No   
PHP
Build Configuration
Version (Run Time)  7.2.3
Version (Compile Time)  7.2.34
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   enabled
Settings
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File   D:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
Directive   Local Value Master Value    Docs
xdebug.mode debug   debug   
xdebug.start_with_request   default default 
xdebug.start_upon_error default default 
xdebug.output_dir   C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp 
xdebug.use_compression  0   0   
xdebug.trigger_value    no value    no value    
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value    
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value    
xdebug.log  no value    no value    
xdebug.log_level    7   7   
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128 
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512 
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3   
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256 
xdebug.cli_color    0   0   
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off 
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0   
xdebug.halt_level   0   0   
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1  
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off 
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value    
xdebug.dump_globals On  On  
xdebug.dump_once    On  On  
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off 
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p   
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off 
xdebug.cloud_id no value    no value    
xdebug.client_host  localhost   localhost   
xdebug.client_port  9003    9003    
xdebug.discover_client_host Off Off 
xdebug.client_discovery_header  no value    no value    
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value    
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms   200 200 
xdebug.scream   Off Off 
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p  
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c    
xdebug.trace_format 0   0   
xdebug.trace_options    0   0   
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off 
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off 
xdebug.remote_autostart (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   
xdebug.remote_enable    (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   
xdebug.remote_host  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   
xdebug.remote_log   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   
xdebug.remote_port  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   `
```

in php.ini [xdebug]:
`

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log="d:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
;xdebug.remote_mode=jit
;xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

`

Comment: Neither PhpStorm nor Xdebug care about function names. The only thing that matters is placing the breakpoint in a debuggable statement (you can't stop execution in e.g. a comment or a blank line) and having correct path mappings so the IDE can find the file reported by Xdebug.

Comment: I placed my breakpoint on php code and both functions are in the same file so there is no reason for this to be an indexing problem.
I never suggested that it had anything to do with the name of the functions.

Comment: Sorry, function names are the only detail you've shared so I assumed you were suspecting something related to that. Yes, I hadn't thought of PhpStorm index being stale, that could be another explanation.

Comment: so no idea of what's wrong ?

Comment: Show your LIVE Xdebug settings / how Xdebug is configured. If request comes from Stripe (a webhook) then it does not have "debug me" flag. So it's normal that Xdebug does not start debugging it. Right now based on your limited info it's all about your Xdebug settings.

Comment: Is it possible that this is because recurring_payment_confirm() is not triggered by a user? It is currently triggered by receiving the http request I added to the post

Comment: How can I access to my "LIVE Xdebug settings" plz?

Comment: there is nothing on my Run/Debug Configurations if this is what you're talking about

Comment: Show the full output of `xdebug_info();` if Xdebug v3 is used or the whole Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` for Xdebug v2. Xdebug needs to see the "debug me flag" (Xdebug cookie or GET/POST parameter) in order to debug. Unless you configure it to start debugging for every single request.

Comment: You can also place `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code -- this will act as programmatic breakpoint (Xdebug will try to establish the debug session)

Comment: I added xdebug_info(); to the post

Comment: how can I set the GET/POST parameter that you mentioned?

Comment: 1) You can set `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` so that Xdebug will debug every single request https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#start_with_request  2) GET parameter -- if it's Stripe's webhook then you can add the needed parameter there in the URL (but it's not super great idea -- you may forget removing it later. For you scenario I would suggest either `start_with_request` option or `xdebug_break()` in PHP code. P.S. Do not forget to restart the web server after making changes in php.ini . Also check https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug

Comment: I put a xdebug_break(); on recurring_payment_confirm(), it work and even makes the stop points work that didn't work before. But last month, I was on another computer, and I didn't need xdebug_break() to make the stop points work in the same place.
I also tried xdebug.start_with_request=yes (without xdebug_break()) and even after restart the web server, it doesn't work. I add [xdebug] of php.ini on the post

Comment: I'm using the chrome extension

Comment: I success to make it work, I pass the authorization of the xdebug chrome extension from "in case of a click" to "on all sites" in addition to add xdebug.start_with_request=yes in php.ini
Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

I success to make it work, I pass the authorization of the xdebug chrome extension from "in case of a click" to "on all sites" in addition to add xdebug.start_with_request=yes in php.ini Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you changed the authorization of the chrome extension?